# loading multy-line text from database into javascript variable error

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to load multi-line text from a MySQL database into a JavaScript variable, but it doesn't work.

I get the text from the database, then add the text to a spring model as its attribute "`mytext`".

In a jsp file, I want to retrieve the text, so I have code like this:

```
 var text = '<c:out value="${mytext}"/>'; //multy-line text
 alert(text);
```

The above code fails, and the function `alert()` would not be called.

If the text from the database is single-line, it goes well.

How can this be fixed in script code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a character sequence to join the multiline text into one line (server side) and then split the text using javascript using the same character sequence.